# WebBrowser и AllowsTransparency. C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser

При использовании `AllowsTransparency = true;` страницы в WebBrowser пропадают, т.е становятся прозрачными (отображается задний фон окна). Если убрать `AllowsTransparency = true;`, то страницы грузятся нормально, но я не могу задавать прозрачность окна. Как решить эту проблему?

`webBrowser1.Opacity = 100;` не помогает.

Comment: Какую вы задачу решаете при помощи `WebBrowser`?

Comment: Просмотр страниц/сайтов из интернета.

Comment: Смотрите в чем вся соль... `WebBrowser` ооооочень многое не поддерживает, честно, я вообще не представляю для чего он был добавлен в C#, то есть вы большинство страниц не сможете через него адекватно просмотреть, особенно те, которые использует новые версии JS и HTML. Если у вас простая html страничка, написанная вами, то может быть (и то не факт), он справится с этой задачей, если же у вас задача просматривать весь интернет, то мой вам совет, откажитесь от `WebBrowser` в пользу чего либо более свежего (например CefSharp - это компонент на базе Chromium).

Comment: А если у вас вовсе задача получить данные с ресурса и распарсить их, то подумайте вовсе, нужен вам "визуал", может стоит просто отправлять POST/GET запросы и получать данные напрямую, минуя html/css/js?

Comment: CefSharp нет одной нужной и важной функции. Но в WebBrowser она есть. Допустим, что у нас есть пустой сайт с кнопкой "Launch App", и по нажатию кнопки открывается приложение, либо как в Chrome "Cайт такой-то такой-то хочет запустить такое-то такое-то приложение". В WebBrowser она работает на ура, но попытавшись сделать так на CefSharp, ничего не удалось. Поэтому мне важна функция запуска приложений из браузера.

Comment: Это уже тема отдельного вопроса и я уверен, что она там тоже есть. Сейчас моя цель предупредить вас, что `WebBrowser` это давно устаревший компонент, который многое вам не откроет и я настоятельно советую отказаться от него.

Comment: Есть еще такая штука - [`WebView`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) или [`WebView2`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/), правда будет работать только Windows 10.